# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE doesn't load correctly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Term.txt file:

```
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

Tab (\t) delimited.

I have table Term:

```
MariaDB [TermDS]> describe Term;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(35) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I wanted to load this file into the table:

```
MariaDB [TermDS]> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/abigail/Term.txt' INTO TABLE Term FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)                  
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

The result isn't correct, because:

```
MariaDB [TermDS]> select * from Term;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | A
2  |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The trouble is that, it doesn't issue any error or warning message. Why doesn't the load succeed?

Comment: your fields are not enclosed by '"'

Comment: I removed the "ENCLOSED BY" part, but get same result.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I should use terminated by '\n', instead of '\r\n'.